# Why inductive datatypes forbid types like `data Bad a = C (Bad a -> a)` where the type recursion occurs in front of ->?

Tags: haskell, recursive-datastructures, algebraic-data-types, y-combinator, agda

Agda manual on [Inductive Data Types and Pattern Matching](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/agda.php?n=ReferenceManual.InductiveDataTypesAndPatternMatching) states:

> To ensure normalisation, inductive occurrences must appear in strictly positive positions. For instance, the following datatype is not allowed:
>
> ```
> data Bad : Set where
>   bad : (Bad → Bad) → Bad
> ```
>
> since there is a negative occurrence of Bad in the argument to the constructor.

Why is this requirement necessary for inductive data types?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The data type you gave is special in that it is an embedding of the *untyped* lambda calculus.

```
data Bad : Set where
  bad : (Bad → Bad) → Bad

unbad : Bad → (Bad → Bad)
unbad (bad f) = f
```

Let's see how. Recall, the untyped lambda calculus has these terms:

```
 e := x | \x. e | e e'
```

We can define a translation `[[e]]` from untyped lambda calculus terms to Agda terms of type `Bad` (though not in Agda):

```
[[x]]     = x
[[\x. e]] = bad (\x -> [[e]])
[[e e']]  = unbad [[e]] [[e']]
```

Now you can use your favorite non-terminating untyped lambda term to produce a non-terminating term of type `Bad`. For example, we could translate `(\x. x x) (\x. x x)` to the non-terminating expression of type `Bad` below:

```
unbad (bad (\x -> unbad x x)) (bad (\x -> unbad x x))
```

Although the type happened to be a particularly convenient form for this argument, it can be generalized with a bit of work to any data type with negative occurrences of recursion.

Comment: Nice answer. I like this elegant approach with it's theoretical explanation (embedding the untyped lambda calculus). Would it be possible to extend it so that it gives arbitrary recursion to the language in question (Agda let's say)?

Comment: @PetrPudlák So, I just chatted with my officemates, who are far and away better type theorists than me. The consensus is that this `Bad` wouldn't give rise to a term of type `forall a. a` (which is what you really care about; recursion is just a means to get there). The argument would go like this: you can construct a set-theoretic model of Agda; then you can add to that model an interpretation of `Bad` as a single-element set; since there are still uninhabited types in the resulting model, there's no function translating looping `Bad` terms into looping terms of another type.

Answer (score 13):

An example how such a data type allows us to inhabit any type is given in Turner, D.A. (2004-07-28), [Total Functional Programming](http://www.jucs.org/jucs_10_7/total_functional_programming), sect. 3.1, page 758 in *Rule 2: Type recursion must be covariant*."

---

Let's make a more elaborate example using Haskell. We'll start with a "bad" recursive data type

```hs
data Bad a = C (Bad a -> a)
```

and construct the [Y combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator) from it without any other form of recursion. This means that having such a data type allows us to construct any kind of recursion, or inhabit any type by an infinite recursion.

The Y combinator in the untyped lambda calculus is defined as

```hs
Y = λf.(λx.f (x x)) (λx.f (x x))
```

The key to it is that we apply `x` to itself in `x x`. In typed languages this is not directly possible, because there is no valid type `x` could possibly have. But our `Bad` data type allows this modulo adding/removing the constructor:

```hs
selfApp :: Bad a -> a
selfApp (x@(C x')) = x' x
```

Taking `x :: Bad a`, we can unwrap its constructor and apply the function inside to `x` itself. Once we know how to do this, it's easy to construct the Y combinator:

```hs
yc :: (a -> a) -> a
yc f =  let fxx = C (\x -> f (selfApp x))  -- this is the λx.f (x x) part of Y
        in selfApp fxx
```

Note that *neither `selfApp` nor `yc` are recursive, there is no recursive call of a function to itself.* Recursion appears only in our recursive data type.

We can check that the constructed combinator indeed does what it should. We can make an infinite loop:

```hs
loop :: a
loop = yc id
```

or compute let's say [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor):

```hs
gcd' :: Int -> Int -> Int
gcd' = yc gcd0
  where
    gcd0  :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int -> Int)
    gcd0 rec a b  | c == 0     = b
                  | otherwise  = rec b c
      where c = a `mod` b
```